# How to create the directory structure using mkdir for directory creation and touch for creating files?

Tags: command-line, bash, directory, mkdir

[image: directory tree]

Command written by me:

```
mkdir -p mydir/{ colors/{basic/{red,blue,green},blended/{yellow,orange,pink}},shape/{circle,square,cube},animals/{mammals/{platypus,bat,dog},reptiles/{snakes,crocodile,lizard}}}
touch mydir/{colors,shape,animals}
```

Output:

```
 common_script.sh  directory.sh 
 mydir  vpl_environment.sh  vpl_execution
    
    ./mydir:
    animals  colors  shape
    
    ./mydir/animals:
    mammals  reptiles
    
    ./mydir/animals/mammals:
    bat  dog  platypus
    
    ./mydir/animals/mammals/bat:
    
    ./mydir/animals/mammals/dog:
    
    ./mydir/animals/mammals/platypus:
    
    ./mydir/animals/reptiles:
    crocodile  lizard  snakes
    
    ./mydir/animals/reptiles/crocodile:
    
    ./mydir/animals/reptiles/lizard:
    
    ./mydir/animals/reptiles/snakes:
    
    ./mydir/colors:
    basic  blended
    
    ./mydir/colors/basic:
    blue  green  red
    
    ./mydir/colors/basic/blue:
    
    ./mydir/colors/basic/green:
    
    ./mydir/colors/basic/red:
    
    ./mydir/colors/blended:
    orange  pink  yellow
    
    ./mydir/colors/blended/orange:
    
    ./mydir/colors/blended/pink:
    
    ./mydir/colors/blended/yellow:
    
    ./mydir/shape:
    circle  cube  square
    
    ./mydir/shape/circle:
    
    ./mydir/shape/cube:
    
    ./mydir/shape/square:
```

Why am I getting those extra lines of output like:

```
    ./mydir/animals/mammals/bat:

    ./mydir/animals/mammals/dog:

    ./mydir/animals/mammals/platypus:


        ./mydir/animals/reptiles/crocodile:
        
        ./mydir/animals/reptiles/lizard:
        
        ./mydir/animals/reptiles/snakes:


        ./mydir/colors/basic/blue:
        
        ./mydir/colors/basic/green:
        
        ./mydir/colors/basic/red:


        ./mydir/colors/blended/orange:
        
        ./mydir/colors/blended/pink:
        
        ./mydir/colors/blended/yellow:


        ./mydir/shape/circle:
        
        ./mydir/shape/cube:
        
        ./mydir/shape/square:
```

Comment: Neither of those commands display any "output". What command did you run that display this output?

Comment: 1 mkdir -p  mydir/{colors/{basic/{red,blue,green},blended/{yellow,orange,pink}},shape/{circle,square,cube},animals/{mammals/{platypus,bat,dog},reptiles/{snakes,crocodile,lizard}}}               3 touch mydir/{colors,shape,animals}

Comment: The  ouput that i added is correct but why i'm getting those extra lines

Comment: Are you showing us the output of an `ls -R` command? which lines exactly are you asking about?

Comment: The ouput that I getting is correct but..I just want to know, Why  i'm getting the lines like                
  ./mydir/animals/mammals/bat:

    ./mydir/animals/mammals/dog:

    ./mydir/animals/mammals/platypus:

Comment: why you get those outputs? because you asked for it... As you do not show us your script(s), we wont be able to help

Comment: Image is added for reference to create directory

Comment: you can use `find` or `shopt -s globstar; ls -d1 **` if you want a recursive 'list'.